# Least squares estimation

Tags: least-squares

everyone!

I have $Y_i = 1 + \frac{a}{X_i} + \epsilon$ dependence between $X$ and $Y$ and I want to get the estimation of parameter $a$ with least squares technique. For this I'm solving this optimization problem:
$$\sum \left(Y_i - \left(1 + \frac{a}{X_i}\right)\right)^2 \longrightarrow \underset{a}{\min}$$
$$ \frac {\partial \sum \left(Y_i - \left(1 + \frac{a}{X_i}\right)\right)^2} {\partial a} = -2 \sum \left(Y_i - 1 - \frac{a}{X_i}\right) * \frac{1}{X_i} = 0$$

So, here, am I able to multiply both parts by $X_i^2$?

If so:
$$ \sum \left(Y_i X_i - X_i - a\right)  = 0$$
$$ \sum X_i (Y_i - 1)  = a * n$$
$$ a = \frac{\sum X_i (Y_i - 1)}{n}$$

Am I doing everything correctly?

Comment: No, you can't do that and maintain an equality in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum\limits_i \left(Y_i - 1 - \frac{a}{X_i}\right) \frac{1}{X_i} = \sum\limits_i \left(\dfrac{Y_i-1}{X_i}\right) - a\sum\limits_i \left(\frac{1}{X_i^2}\right)=0$

$\Rightarrow a = \dfrac{\sum\limits_i \left(\dfrac{Y_i-1}{X_i}\right)}{\sum\limits_i \left(\frac{1}{X_i^2}\right)}$